# Нужна запятая между однородными членами предложения?

Tags: однородные-члены

Сегодня и элитарная, и народная культуры сохранили своих почитателей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Сегодня и элитарная, и народная культуры сохранили своих почитателей.*

Запятая ставится, если однородные члены связаны повторяющимся союзом И. Исключение (отсутствие запятой) возможно при близком единстве однородных членов. В данном случае такого единства нет.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

2. При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом и, запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов): Кругом было и светло и зелено (Т.); Он носил и лето и зиму старую жокейскую кепку (Пауст.); Прибрежная полоса, пересечённая мысами, уходила и в ту и в другую сторону (Сем.); Он был и весел и печален в одно и то же время.

Answer (score 2):

[Лопатин](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/):

> §26 При двукратном повторении союза и  (если число однородных членов –
>   два) запятая ставится при наличии обобщающего слова при однородных
>   членах предложения: Всё напоминало об осени: и желтые листья, и туманы
>   по утрам  ; то же без обобщающего слова, но при наличии зависимых слов
>   при однородных членах: Теперь уж можно было расслышать в отдельности и
>   шум дождя, и шум воды  (Булг.).
>   Однако при отсутствии указанных
>   условий при однородных членах предложения, образующих тесное смысловое
>   единство, запятая может не ставиться: Кругом было и светло и зелено 
>   (Т.); И днем и ночью кот ученый все ходит по цепи кругом (П.).

**Сегодня и *элитарная*, и *народная* культуры сохранили своих почитателей.**

В вашем предложении есть обобщающее слово — *культуры* (культура элитарная, культура народная), стало быть, запятая ставится.

Comment: Здесь нет обобщающего слова, просто два определения относятся к одному существительному.

Comment: А в таком случае: _Культуры: и элитарная, и народная и сегодня сохранили своих почитателей_?

Comment: Тогда о. с. есть, и оформление такое: Культуры: и элитарная, и народная и - сегодня сохранили своих почитателей.

Comment: @Ксения Понятно, спасибо.

Comment: Это ужасная фраза, и никакая правильная пунктуация ее не спасает.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написал так:

**Сегодня мы видим, что и элитарная, и народная культура сохранили своих почитателей.**

Слово "культура" чаще употребляется в ед. ч.

Да и вообще по Розенталю ([§194. Два определения при одном существительном](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm)):

> 4) если перечисляемые разновидности предметов или явлений внутренне связаны, например, в сочетаниях терминологического характера: ср.: в правой и левой руке (половине, стороне и т.п.); оперное и балетное искусство; промышленный и аграрный переворот; учащиеся среднего и старшего школьного возраста; программы для восьмилетней и средней школы (как системы образования); в старославянском и древнерусском книжном языке; глаголы совершенного и несовершенного вида (действительного и страдательного залога, настоящего и прошедшего времени, изъявительного и сослагательного наклонения, первого и второго спряжения и т.п.); существительные мужского, женского и среднего рода (первого и второго склонения, единственного и множественного числа); местоимения первого и второго лица; вирусный и простой грипп; головной и спинной мозг; война Алой и Белой розы.
>
> Ср. также: Город был открыт для ветров с северной и восточной стороны.
>
> Сказуемое в этих случаях ставится в форме множественного числа, например: Правая и левая половина дома были освещены; Прошедшее и будущее время глагола указывают на предшествующее и последующее действие по отношению к моменту речи;

Дополнение 1. Культура — абстрактное существительное. Сошлюсь на точку зрения В. В. Виноградова (Виноградов В. В. Современный русский язык), хотя некоторые и считают ее устаревшей. Он  рассматривал абстрактные, вещественные и собирательные существительные как разряд слов, "обнаруживающих только формы единственного числа и вовсе не относимых ко множественному, так как они не соединяются с представлением о счете"

Дополнение 2. Выражение "почитатели элитарной/народной культуры" вызывает сомнение. Вряд ли корректно говорить о *почитании* культуры. Я бы предложил использовать слово *приверженцы*.

Дополнение 3. "Сохранили" указывает на завершенный процесс, но в данном контексте он был длительным, не процессом одного дня. Как это сочетается с *сегодня*? Сохраняли, сохраняли, а сегодня, наконец, сохранили (?!). Более формальный подход: *сегодня* в данном контексте означает *в данный момент времени*, то есть настоящее, лишенное длительности, а *сохранили* — глагол прошедшего времени, процесс, который завершился в прошлом.